# Why does behat call my context class twice?

Tags: php, behat

When I want run my behat test like in [this tutorial](http://www.magecasts.io/tdd/behat-part3.html), I get an error message:

```
➜  test.dev bin/behat --suite=system
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class SystemContext in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.dev/features/bootstrap/SystemContex.php on line 12
```

And I do not know why, because I wrote my `behat.yml` like at [this page](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/5.suites.html#suite-paths):

```
default:
    suites:
        site:
            paths: [ %paths.base%/features/site ]
            contexts: [ SiteContext ]
        system:
            paths: [ %paths.base%/features/system ]
            contexts: [ SystemContex ]
extensions:
    MageTest\MagentoExtension\Extension: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url: 'http://test.dev/'
        selenium2:
            wd_host: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
            browser: firefox
```

My file structure is like:

```
project-dir
├── behat.yml
├── bin
│   └── behat
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── features
│   ├── bootstrap
│   │   ├── FeatureContext.php
│   │   ├── SiteContext.php
│   │   └── SystemContext.php
│   ├── site
│   │   └── ...
│   └── system
│       └── check_baseurl.feature
├── htdocs
│   ├── app
│   ├── downloader
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── js
│   ├── skin
│   ├── var
│   └── ...
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    ├── behat
    ├── magetest
    └── ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important:** several problems occur because you copy and paste behat.yml from website to your behat.yml - there are sometimes whitespaces, that you can't see but will effect your behat system!!!

You should re-write the `behat.yml`, the context mentioned in behat.yml is wrong. It should be as follow.

`default: 

       suites: 

          default: 

             paths: 

                 features: features/site 

                 contexts: 

                      - SiteContext 

          system: 

             paths:      [ %paths.base%/features/system ]
             contexts:   [ SystemContext  ]`

By default context is searched in bootstrap folder, you just have to mention the filename of the context file.

And to execute the suite execute the following command

```
bin/behat --suite=system
```

**Note:** use `bin/behat` in command if you are executing suite from project root directory. If you are in `bin` folder just use `behat` before execution

Comment: @Jurik I have updated the answer, your system suite should be aligned with default, and command for executing is different as I have mentioned it in answer

Comment: Thanks, but I figured out that everything is good in my behat.yml - my problem was that I copy & pasted from a website. This caused some whitespace issues.
My config is just like in the behat docs.

Comment: Ahhh... yml files sucks.. faced same issues before anyways good luck