# How to setup Behat for Magento on Mac with MAMP?

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, bdd, php

We have a Magento shop and want BDD-tests for our system - locally and later on server side. How can I setup an Behat environment on my mac with MAMP?

Answer (score 2):

This is my first try to setup Behat Magetest for Magento on my MacOS - my tests run quite well and I want to share my experience.

[image: My Behat test worked well with PHPStorm Behat plugin]

First of all you should download MAMP Pro and Magento, if you did not do it already. It works without MAMP too - but that is how I did it - so feel free to work without MAMP. My final tests are based on the sample data provided by Magento, so get them as well.

- **System:** Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.3)
- **MAMP Pro:** [3.5](https://www.mamp.info/de/downloads/) (sorry for german interface screenshots in MAMP, do not know how to set it to english)
- **Magento:** [1.9.1.0](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download#download1757) , [Sample Data](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download#download1759)
- **Java:** [Version 8 Update 74](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

So let us start:

**Setup Environment with MAMP Pro:**

After installing MAMP I use the standard ports (80, 443, 3306).
[image: Setup ports for your apache and mysql server]

Under PHP I'm using Version 5.6.10 - I guess there won't be big differences when you take 5.4.x, but this is at least recommended. And activate xDebug - it is always nice to have a good debugger.
[image: Activate xDebug for php]

Now you go to the 'Hosts'-tab and create a domain called `test.dev` and its document root should be at `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.dev/html`.
[image: Create your test environment host]

Since we will work alot with CLI we need MAMP Pros PHP run there as well. Use following command in your CLI:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin:$PATH
```

You can put this line into your home folder/.bash_profile so you do not need to do this every time again.

If you do not do this you will have [database connection problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573676/why-can-magento-behat-test-not-find-my-database/35581565).

Now start your web and database server.

**Setup Magento**

Before you copy any Magento data use this command in your CLI and restart your finder (ALT+Rightclick). Now you can see hidden files as well like .htaccess.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

You downloaded [Magento 1.9.1.0](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download#download1757) and the [Sample Data](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download#download1759) and extract them in your document root (`/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.dev/html`). Then you create a database e.g. `testdb` and import the sql from the sample data.

Now you can open `http://test.dev` in your browser and you should see the installation process of Magento. That should be quite easy to finish.

If any errors occur: check your file and directory access. With MAMP you can change all the access rights to user `www`.

**Setup Behat with composer**

Composer is a tool that installs software with all dependencies. You will love it!

Now [install composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/):

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" > composer-setup.php
php -r "if (hash('SHA384', file_get_contents('composer-setup.php')) === 'fd26ce67e3b237fffd5e5544b45b0d92c41a4afe3e3f778e942e43ce6be197b9cdc7c251dcde6e2a52297ea269370680') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); }"
php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Now create the behat installation file for composer `composer.json` in your project root - *NOT* webroot - it should be one level above webroot.

Your directory tree should look like this:

```
test.dev (project directory)
├── composer.json
└── html
    ├── app
    ├── downloader
    ├── index.php
    ├── js
    ├── skin
    ├── var
    └── ...
```

Now we configure the installation of behat in our composer.json file:

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "behat/behat": "3.0.*",
    "magetest/magento-behat-extension": "dev-feature/Behat3",
    "bossa/phpspec2-expect": "~1.0",
    "peridot-php/webdriver-manager": "dev-master",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "1.1.*",
    "emagister/selenium-server": "2.*"
  },
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "MageTest\\PhpSpec\\MagentoExtension": "src",
      "": [
        "html/app/code/local",
        "html/app/code/community",
        "html/app/code/core",
        "html/app",
        "html/lib",
        "features/bootstrap"
      ],
      "Mage" : "html/app/code/core"
    }
  }
}
```

*Hint:* `html/app/code/local` is only needed if you have own modules/features - at the moment it should not exist.

Now you can run composer and it will install all needed packages:

```
composer install
```

If you change anything late, just use this instead of install:

```
composer update
```

Now your directory tree should look like:

```
project-dir
├── bin
│   ├── behat
│   ├── manager
│   ├── phpspec
│   └── selenium-server.jar
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── htdocs
│   ├── app
│   ├── downloader
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── js
│   ├── skin
│   ├── var
│   └── ...
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    ├── behat
    ├── magetest
    └── ...
```

Very good - now we can finally setup `behat`! We create a `behat.yml` file in our project directory with following content:

```
default:
    suites:
        site:
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/site ]
            contexts:
                - SiteContext
        system:
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/system ]
            contexts:
                - SystemContext
    extensions:
        MageTest\MagentoExtension\Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://test.dev/
            selenium2:
                browser: chrome
```

*Hint:* You **REALLY** have to be carefull with copy paste this code from internet. Because it is like Python - every indent space is important and other white spaces will cause [strange behaviors](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17237/why-does-behat-call-my-context-class-twice). I use 4 indent spaces.

We start with two suites, because I want have backend tests for our system and frontend tests for our webpage. Of course you can do as many suites as you want - just check the [documentation](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/5.suites.html).

Now we initialize our behat environment with:

```
bin/behat --init
```

Your directory tree should look like:

```
project-dir
├── behat.yml
├── bin
│   └── behat
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── features
│   ├── bootstrap
│       ├── SiteContext.php
│       └── SystemContext.php
│   ├── site
│   └── system
├── htdocs
│   ├── app
│   └── ...
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    └── ...
```

Before we define our first tests let us finish the last two steps of setup the environment.

I want work with Chrome instead of Firefox. That is why our selenium server needs this information. Now we need the chromedriver and since I am really lazy and I really like installation scripts, we get homebrew and install it with this package dependency tool (somehow I did not find chromedriver package for composer):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install node
brew install chromedriver
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/chromedriver/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.chromedriver.plist
```

To start our selenium server we need [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). After installing it you can run following command in a new terminal window:

```
java -jar bin/selenium-server.jar
```

Do not close this terminal window or the server will be shut down. It is cool to read a few lines and get more information about what this server does actually.

That is it! Webserver + database + Selenium server is running - good job!

**Define first tests**

Since I started this project with [this howto](http://www.magecasts.io/tdd/behat-part3.html) I will use the test cases as well.

Create a `check_baseurl.feature` file in your `test.dev/features/system` folder with following content:

```
Feature: Testing that behat and magento are working together
  In order to continue working on Magento
  As a magento developer     
  I need to be able to configure behat and magento

  Scenario: Base URL is configured in the database
    Given there is a base_url configuration option set
    Then I should see the value being "http://test.dev/"
```

When you run following command behat will create all necessary methods in your `SystemContext.php` file:

```
bin/behat --suite=system --append-snippets
```

Now you should see that behat created two methods in your `SystemContext.php`:
[image: Behat created two methods in our SystemContext.php]

Now we complete our functions and our `SystemContext.php` should look like:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use MageTest\MagentoExtension\Context\MagentoContext;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class SystemContext extends MagentoContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext {


    /**
     * @Given there is a base_url configuration option set
     */
    public function thereIsABaseUrlConfigurationOptionSet()
    {
        $this->baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    }

    /**
     * @Then I should see the value being :arg1
     */
    public function iShouldSeeTheValueBeing($arg1)
    {
        expect($this->baseUrl)->toBe($url);
    }
}
```

*Hint:* Best is to copy & paste this code to your `SystemContext.php` because the class extends now from MagentoContext as well.

Now - excitement! - we run our first Behat test:

```
bin/behat --suite=system
```

[image: Your first behat test passed!]

Awesome!

Now we see our finish line already! Next test is in our chrome browser!
We create now `item_to_cart.feature` in our `test.dev/features/site/` folder with following content:

```
Feature: Visitor can add items to the cart and shop
  In order to make a purchase
  As a visitor to the site     
  I need to be able to see the product page and add the item to the cart

  Scenario: Adding the item to the cart
    Given I am on a product page
    When I add the item to the cart
    Then I should see that the total items in my basket is "1"
```

And run again our command to generate our methods:

```
bin/behat --suite=site --append-snippets
```

You should see three new methods in your `SiteContext.php` file - fill them with life:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use MageTest\MagentoExtension\Context\MagentoContext;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class SiteContext extends MagentoContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext {

    /**
     * @Given I am on a product page
     */
    public function iAmOnAProductPage() {
        $this->getSession()->visit(Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'accessories/eyewear/aviator-sunglasses.html');
    }

    /**
     * @When I add the item to the cart
     */
    public function iAddTheItemToTheCart() {
        $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', '.add-to-cart-buttons .btn-cart')->click();
    }

    /**
     * @Then I should see that the total items in my basket is :total
     */
    public function iShouldSeeThatTheTotalItemsInMyBasketIs($total) {
        $pageTotal = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', '.count')->getText();
        expect($pageTotal)->toBe($total);
    }
}
```

*Hint:* I had to add another css class to `iAddTheItemToTheCart` function because otherwise selenium would tell us that the button is invisible. Because there are two buttons on this page with same `.btn-cart` css class and the first one is `display:none`. I do not know why it worked in this [howto](http://www.magecasts.io/tdd/behat-part3.html).

And finally fire:

```
bin/behat --suite=site
```

Awesome! A Chrome instance should open and do the test stuff while you lean back and watch and a few seconds later you should see something like this:

[image: Your first chrome web test passed!]

That's it! Really! Now you can write many cool tests and expand your test environment.

***Hint:*** since this is my first try to install behat by my own, there might be a better configuration - feel free to edit any parts.

Comment: Cool man thanks for sharing your own solution. :)